# how can set the different languages in Google play store?

Tags: google-play

how can set the different languages in Google play store?

I hope I can use different language release in Google play store.

[image]

I have write the English name in Main store listing, and Chinese name. But I don't know why it's always display Chinese name. Where has a problem?

The dashboard will show English name, but when I click the link(view on Google Play), it's will show Chinese.

[image]

[image]

I had tried to add &hl=en-GB or &hl=en-AU in URL, but it's still show Chinese.

How can I do? I want to show two languages Enhlish & Chinese. When I want to promote in Australia, the link I posted can display the English version, but when I promote in Taiwan, I want the link content to display Chinese.

This is link: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.luvtas.camping

Comment: You have already added Chinese translation, if a device's language is set to chinese your game page will appear in chinese.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Play store listing takes the language of the device. So probably your device language is Chinese so it is displaying in Chinese. if you change it to english, then it will show in english.
Please refer [here](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9844778?hl=en)

Also, I see your app in english :

[image: store listing]

Comment: OKay, I got it. So if my device default English it''s will show English name.